# How do i convert a String [][] to a List containing String []

Tags: java

I am having trouble with my code... I am getting this error message: Cannot invoke toList() on the array type String [][]

How do i convert a String [][] to a List containing String []

in JAVA

```
    frame.getContentPane().add(comboBoxGetFile);
btnGetInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String choice = comboBoxGetInfo.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(choice == "Customers") {
            List<String[]> list = proxy.getAllCustomersInfo().toList();
        }
    }
})
```

I want it to fill a table, not print anything with a sys.out

After some changes I have this:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(comboBoxGetFile);
    btnGetInfo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String choice = (String)comboBoxGetInfo.getSelectedItem();
            if(choice.equals("Customers")) {
                try {
                    List<String[]> list = Arrays.asList(proxy.getAllCustomersInfo());
                    //List<String[]> list = Arrays.stream(proxy.getAllCustomersInfo()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    dtm.setColumnCount(4);
                    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(colsForShowingCustomers);
                    for (String[] sa : list){
                        dtm.addRow(sa);
                    }

                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you try to google around first?

Comment: Yes, I have googled, but dont really know how to... I am quite new to this...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, try this:

```
List<String[]> list = Arrays.stream(proxy.getAllCustomersInfo()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works just fine:

```
package eu.webfarmr;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ListArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] array = new String[][]{{"hello", "example", "one"},
                                          {"cheerio", "another example", "two"}
                                    };
        List<String[]> list = Arrays.asList(array);

        for (String[] a : list){
            for (String s : a){
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints the following out:

```
hello
example
one
cheerio
another example
two
```